# Magento 2 - Move Product Details Tab Accordion

Tags: magento2, product-view, tabs

I am working on magento 2.2. On the product page, there is a detail accordion before the related product slider. Though the accordion is on the left side of the page only, I want this tab structure to cover the full page width. Take a look at this: https://prnt.sc/iztid6

I tried updating `app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Catalog/layout/ catalog_product_view.xml` and `/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/ frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` files but the closest that I have reached is that I got the full width structure but the order of tabs gets changed. The order of the tabs should be *details*, *more info*, *review tabs*.

Please guide me how can I achieve the full tab structure.

Answer (score 0):

This theme had made modifications to catalog_product_view changing the original structure, adding sidebar at product page.

If you want to strech to full width your details block you need to move them before products related. But i can tell you right now, your details tab will be too far from the main product because the sidebar is to higher.

Can you post the content of `/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/ frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` ?

Comment: Thanks @ovitinho , 
the sidebar is not an issue for me as i will change the sidebar to half of its current size.

There are 2 files 1) /public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml  (2) /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/ layout/catalog_product_view.xml .  

Here is the code of (2) https://pastebin.com/MRPAHzzF .  The module related products is coming from (1) now when i add product description on (1) though the tabs gets full with but the order of tabs get changed.

Comment: Please help me crack this. @emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd please check, you might help me solve this issue